# How to store an identifier in a ListView a client connection - Indy 10

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe2, indy10

I am creating a TCP server which receives multiple clients and must be able to send messages to each.

How do I get a handle to the client connection and then send arbitrary data?

Thanks: D

Code:

```
procedure TFRM_Main.ServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
var lAdd: TListItem;
var Index: integer;
begin
  lAdd := ListView.Items.Add;
  //AContext connection ID, what to do here?
  lAdd.Caption := IntToStr(Index);
end;
```

Comment: @DorinDuminica Ready, code added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.Write( (* bytes *) );
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteFile( (* send a file to the client *) );
```

For more options, just invoke the code completion(CTRL+SPACE) after IOHandler and see available options, some time ago, I've wrote a simple client/server test app, click [here](http://www.delphigeist.com/2010/09/custom-client-server-application-with.html) to see and/or download source.

Answer (score 2):

`TIdTCPServer` is a multithreaded component. Accessing the UI directly from within its `OnConnect` event (or `OnDisconnect`, `OnExecute`, or `OnException`) is not thread-safe! You need to use Indy's `TIdSync` or `TIdNotify` class to access the UI safely.

To answer the original question, the simpliest, but not necessarily the safest, way is to store the `TIdContext.Connection` object pointer in the `TListItem.Data` property. The main thread code will then have direct access to the connection when it needs it.

I do not advise that, though. A safer solution is to uniquely identify each client yourself, such as with a username that the client sends, and store that ID in the `TIdContext.Data` and `TListItem.Data` properties. Then, when your main thread code wants to send a message to a client, it can loop through the `TIdTCPServer.Contexts` list looking for the desired ID, and if found then it will have access to the corresponding `TIdContext.Connection` object.